# Code running differently in different environments

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, spyder, google-colaboratory

In the new Udacity Tensorflow course, the CNN lesson in the linked Colab notebook has a code that uses the Fashion MNIST dataset. Running the code inside the Colab produces 92% accuracy. However, copying the code into Spyder on my PC, without changing a single word, produces a maximum 20% accuracy, going down to a final 11%.

My PC (Windows 10, 64-bit) runs Anaconda 3 with the Spyder 3.3.2 IDE for Python 3.7.1. I made sure to copy and run the code chunks in the same order. For a reference, in a previous lesson that did not use convolution layers, the output in Spyder was similar to that in the Colab.

Link to the relevant Colab (I assume it can be shared since the course is free):
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Cmj8Y4v5RdMn7N2HqyYul32Y4QT-s4aC

I want to understand what the differences are between the Colab env. and my PC env. that make for these changed outputs. Please let me know if there's any information I can add to this question.

Comment: are you sure using the same tensorflow version ? and same dataset ? and also are you using the gpu in both of the environment ?

Comment: @Vaibhavgusain I double checked and am using the same TF version which uses the same dataset import, and in Spyder I used `with tf.device('/GPU')` to implement GPU processing for TF, but still my model comes out with 10% accuracy.